# MySQL How do I use SELECT to get certain columns first and then the rest

Tags: mysql

I want to make a query which will get all columns (like SELECT * FROM Table) from a table but leading with a specific column (like SELECT Table.C, Table.*) without the duplicated column

```
>SELECT * FROM Table

A | B | C | D | ...

1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; ...
```

---

```
>SELECT Table.C, Table.* FROM Table

C | A | B | C | D | ...

3 ; 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; ...
```

---

```
>?


C | A | B | D | ...

3 ; 1 ; 2 ; 4 ; ...
```

*context*

I have multiple tables with a similar structure each having columns like: Date, Time, Count, Quality, and then other columns more specific to the database, and I am making a program that uses a Query to get all of this information

Comment: SELECT leading_column, column, column 
FROM table_name

just write them one by one, it's even better for performance to write the columns rather than SELECT *

Comment: I am using SELECT * since the columns in the different Tables are varied (i.e. Failure Modes)
I get the Idea that a specific solution for a table is best but I am looking for a flexible solution

Comment: If you identify the column not by its name/alias but by its position in the output then you have serious ideological problems in th architecture of your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the `*` wildcard always maps to *all* the columns of the respective table, not some of the columns.

The conventional way to specify the order of columns is to write out all the column names explicitly.

The only alternatives I can suggest are:

- Change the order of columns in your base table.
- Make a `VIEW` that reorders the columns as you would like.
- Make a common table expression that reorders the columns as you would like.
- Don't rely on the order of columns. Write application code to present the columns in whatever order you want, regardless of the order they appear in the result set.